# Ошибка при работе с базами данных mssql (asp.net)

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net

Я разработал модели и контекст, чтобы можно было связать эти модели с таблицами в бд. Но почему-то при любом обращении к полученным данным приложение отказывается запускаться (пишет ожидание ответа от localhost...) так же ошибки никакой не выдаёт.

Модели:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Designer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public double RentPerHour { get; set; }
}

public class Lease
{
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ActualReturnDate { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

 public class LeaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Lease> Leases { get; set; }
    }

  public class LeaseDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LeaseContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(LeaseContext db)
        {
            db.Cars.Add(new Car { Designer = "audi", Model = "a6", RentPerHour = 13.95 });
            db.Cars.Add(new Car { Designer = "bmw", Model = "x5", RentPerHour = 12.04 });

            base.Seed(db);
        }
    }
```

Так же инициализация есть в global.asax

```
Database.SetInitializer(new LeaseDbInitializer());
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему.

Comment: добавь Id в класс Lease, в Seed сохрани изменения db.SaveChanges()

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению это не помогло.Буду искать ответ в документации.